# Webpack export breaks js

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, webpack, react-dom

I'm making a react application using node, express. But suddenly i get this error "Uncaught SytaxError: Unexpected Token :"

And breaks at this line :

```
/***/ function(module, exports) {

module.exports = 
C:\Users\Dimotro\Desktop\queffect\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?http://localhost:3333;
/***/ },
```

This is what i can see in the browser-console. React-dev-tools compiles perfectly with no errors.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: requested files

App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
var app = express();
var json = require('body-parser').json;
import GET_QUEST_DATA from './assets/constants';

class Header extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div id="header">
                <div className="header-box">
                    <ul className="menu">
                        <li className="menu-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li className="menu-item"><a href="#">Queffect</a></li>
                        <li className="menu-item"><a href="#">Sup4port</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class Content extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div id="content">
                <div className="content-box">
                    <Calculator />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Calculator = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="calculator-container">
            <h1 className="calculator title">Queffect</h1>
            <bold>is a calculator that get's your quest requirements done, effectively.</bold>
            <div className="character col-sm-4">
                I'm <input className="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"/> and my objective is a
                <select>
                    <option>Quest</option>
                    <option>Skill</option>
                </select>
                <select>
                    <option>Attack</option>
                    <option>Strenght</option>
                    <option>Defence</option>
                    <option>Ranged</option>
                    <option>Prayer</option>
                    <option>Magic</option>
                    <option>Constitution</option>
                    <option>Crafting</option>
                    <option>Mining</option>
                    <option>Smithing</option>
                    <option>Fishing</option>
                    <option>Cooking</option>
                    <option>Firemaking</option>
                    <option>Woodcutting</option>
                    <option>Runecrafting</option>
                    <option>Dungeoneering</option>
                    <option>Agility</option>
                    <option>Herblore</option>
                    <option>Thieving</option>
                    <option>Fletching</option>
                    <option>Slayer</option>
                    <option>Farming</option>
                    <option>Construction</option>
                    <option>Hunter</option>
                    <option>Summoning</option>
                    <option>Deviation</option>
                    <option>Invention</option>
                </select>
                <button className="update">Guide me</button>
            </div>
            <div className="path col-sm-8">
                {console.log(GET_QUEST_DATA("Gixy"))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
        <Header />
        <Content />
        </div>,
        document.getElementById('app')
);

export default {};
```

webpack.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 3333
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ],
        noParse: ['ws']
    },
    externals: [/^(?!\.|\/).+/i, 'ws']
}
```

Comment: include your webpack config code and your index.js code for us to help

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Included.